# How can I programmatically put my data into grid in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of data in an excel file, for instance:

```
RIH2329
SCC272
CRT041
WS13-14
WS13-16
RIH2602
VT001
CRT035
RIH2874
RIH2876
CRT067
RIH2744
RIH2750
RIH2368
RIH2374
RIH2378
RIH2376
RIH2373...etc
```

I want to put this data into a 9x9 grid. Like this:

```
RIH2329 SCC272 CRT041 WS13-14 WS13-16 RIH2602 VT001 CRT035 RIH2874
RIH2876 CRT067 RIH2744 RIH2750 RIH2368 RIH2374 RIH2378 RIH2376 RIH2373...etc
```

I have lots of data so its impossible to do by hand. I've tried using 
`=offset` to get the data where I want, but this is untenable because I would need to alter each line of code. Is there an easy way to do accomplish what I want without editing every line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `RIH2329` in A1, put this in B1:

```
=OFFSET($A$1, MOD(COLUMN(A:A)-1, 9)+(ROW(1:1)-1)*9, 0)
```

Fill right to J1 then fill B1:J1 down to B9:J9.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with this VBA macro code.

```
Sub makeDataGrid()

Range("A1").Activate 'asumes data starts at this cel
'Put all data into memory down to the bottom assumes there are no blank cells in between
data = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Value
'Delete column containing all data
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Delete

colOffset = 0
rowOffset = 0
For i = 1 To UBound(data)
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Value = data(i, 1)
    colOffset = colOffset + 1
    If colOffset = 9 Then
        colOffset = 0
        rowOffset = rowOffset + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

The macro will remove the column containing all the data after it puts it in an array and then create the grid.